# Determine how many new Y/N results are required to bring Y percentage to N

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This may be high school level (or worse), but I'm not very well versed in algebra and I failed to provide my buddy an equation to determine this.

#### Problem

The problem is he has a survey with a single "yes" or "no" response (think customer satisfaction), which he has to maintain at 85%. Given a current number of surveys and responses given, he wants to know how many more all-"yes" responses would bring the percent up to 85%.

#### Information known

1. The number of surveys given
2. The number of "yes" responses
3. The desired percentage of "yes" responses

#### Example

For instance, if there are currently 90 surveys given and 75 of them were" yes", that would mean 10 more surveys with all "yes" responses are needed to bring the percent up to 85%, since 10 more "yes" responses would put the total surveys at 100 and total "yes" responses at 85.

I realize this isn't very practical, since one cannot predict the ratio of "yes" to "no" responses that will come in, but it made me curious whether there was a single, somewhat simple equation or formula that could be used to determine this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be $y$ yes responses and $n$ no responses so far.  You are asking what number  $k$ of new yes responses makes $y+k$ be $85\%$ of the total, so
$$\frac {y+k}{y+n+k}=0.85\\y+k=0.85(y+n+k)\\0.15(y+k)=0.85n\\y+k=\frac {0.85}{0.15}n\\k=\frac {0.85}{0.15}n-y$$
I think the most enlightening equation is the fourth.  Given $n$ no responses, this gives the total number of yes responses needed.  The last equation just subtracts off the ones you already have.

Comment: That is freaking awesome, thanks a ton! I am going back to my friend to pretend I’m smarter than I am!